# vscode poping up some weird texts on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I save my code on vscode this popup is showing every time. I tried to disable all the extensions but still same issue.

I am using Macos.

[image]

Comment: there is some space after `string` is this a unicode character that has no glyph

Comment: @rioV8 that space i added to replicate the issue. It just appears randomly out of nowhere

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue it was the mac issue

I had to run this command in terminal `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

and then reboot the system